# Making Parentheses optional in regular expression

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I try to validate a text input to match a pattern using regular expression in jQuery validator which accepts number of figures and sub-figures example: `1,2,3(a),4(b),5`

I want to make parentheses optional:

```
$.validator.addMethod("regx", function(value, element, regexpr) { 

return this.optional(element) || /^^\d\((.)\)+(,\d\((.)\)+)*$/i.test(value);
}, "Please enter valid numbers separated by a ', '");
```

Comment: Something like [`/^\d+(?:\([^()]+\))?(?:,\d+(?:\([^()]+\))?)*$/`](https://regex101.com/r/rE1nN8/1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest building the regex you need from blocks for better readability and maintainability:

```
$.validator.addMethod("regx", function(value, element, regexpr) { 
  var digits = "\\d+";                              // 1 or more digits...
  var digits_parens = digits + "(?:\\([^()]+\\))?"; // followed with an optional parenthetical substring having no ( and ) inside
  var rx = "^" + digits_parens + "(?:,\\s*" + digits_parens + ")*$"; // Final pattern
  return this.optional(element) || RegExp(rx).test(value);
}, "Please enter valid numbers separated by a ', '");
```

The resulting pattern will look like:

```
^\d+(?:\([^()]+\))?(?:,\s*\d+(?:\([^()]+\))?)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rE1nN8/2)

Where:

- `^` - start of the string
- `\d+(?:\([^()]+\))?` - 1+ digit(s) followed with 1 or 0 parnetheses
- `(?:,\s*\d+(?:\([^()]+\))?)*` - 0+ sequences of the above subpattern after a `,` followed with 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`)
- `$` - end of string.

Note there is no need using `/i` modifier since there are no letters that can be used case-insensitively inside the pattern.